# Insert 1, 2, 3... numbers before H2 title

Tags: wordpress

How to modify the following code so that the numbers in the orange box before the title of H2 can be displayed as numbers 1, 2, 3...?

Sample website article:
https://weblai.co/css-title/

The following is the code:

```
add_action('wp_head',function(){ ?>
    <style>
        @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Noto+Sans+TC');
        body {font-family: 'Noto Sans TC', sans-serif;}/*思源黑體*/
 article .ast-post-format- .entry-content h2:before {
 content: counter(chapter) "";
 color: #fff;
            background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, #805300 0%, #805300 1%, #F59F00 100%);
            box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
            border-radius: 3px;
            padding: 0 0.8rem;
            margin: 0 0.8rem 0 0;
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ghpc8.png)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using the counter(chapter) without initializing it.

Add the following before the body rule:

```
body {
  counter-reset: chapter;                       /* Set a counter named 'section', and its initial value is 0. */
}
```

Source:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Lists_and_Counters/Using_CSS_counters